# Filter a file based on an object of string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a SQL restore script (file on file system) that contains a list of databases to be restored like so:

RESTORE DATABASE DB1...
RESTORE DATABASE DB2...
RESTORE DATABASE DB3...

I then have an object that contains a list of databases that are already online.

$onlineDatabases.Database outputs
DB1
DB2

How can I return a new restore script that contains only the DB3 database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$online_databases = new-object psobject -property @{database = @("DB1","DB2")}
$test_script = "RESTORE DATABASE DB1","RESTORE DATABASE DB2","RESTORE DATABASE DB3"

[regex]$online_regex = "RESTORE DATABASE " + '(‘ + (($online_databases.database |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)’
$new_script = $test_script -notmatch $online_regex

$new_script

RESTORE DATABASE DB3
```

Replace the $test_script with get-content on your script file, and pipe $new_script to out-file to save it.

Comment: When I run this in my script, $new_script returns True instead of the script.

Comment: Scratch that it was a PowerShell ISE fail.  It is returning nothing.  I will see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Here's an explanation of that regex if it helps: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/18/speed-up-array-comparisons-in-powershell-with-a-runtime-regex.aspx

Comment: Thanks man, I had to tweak it a bit because there was something wrong with my object.  I think because Database was listed as a NoteProperty?  I had to use $onlineDatabases and then convert your Regex to a string and then find and replace on {Database= to "" and on } and on \@  after I did that it worked!!!! Thanks man, I don't know why my search skills didn't turn up the link, but you helped me get unblocked on my project.  I appreciate it.